# Confusing behaviour on passing object as parameter to a method called from Table created in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm have a table with buttons in each row. On every button click I want to pass that row's data to a method. I've done the following

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="load()" >Click</button>
        <table id="roleTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>EnterpriseId</td>
                    <td>Role</td>
                    <td>UserId</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function load() {
    var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loginInfo"));
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].ENTERPRISE_ID + "</td>";
        html += "<td><button type='button' onclick='loadSegment(data[" + i + "])'>...</button></td>";
        html += "<td>" + data[i].USER_ID + "</td></tr>";
    }
    document.getElementById('roleTable').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].innerHTML = html;
}

function loadSegment(o) {
    alert('reading obj');
    alert(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

The problem is when I click on the button with given code, nothing happens.

But if I move the code of **load()** function out, the loadSegment method gets called and I'm able to use the object as I want.

**Working JS**

```
//function load() { // Commented the function call
var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loginInfo"));

var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].ENTERPRISE_ID + "</td>";
    html += "<td><button type='button' onclick='loadSegment(data[" + i + "])'>...</button></td>";
    html += "<td>" + data[i].USER_ID + "</td></tr>";
}
document.getElementById('roleTable').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].innerHTML = html;
//}


function loadSegment(o) {
    alert('reading obj');
    alert(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

I don't understand why through the second code the method is reachable but not from the first code. If I don't pass object as parameter in the first code then it is able to reach to the `loadSegment()` function.

Can anybody please help me understand what is the exact issue her. And how can I achieve the function call from the first JS code.

**Update**

**JSON string**

```
[{"USER_ID":"UID00007","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin1","ROLE":"ADMIN"},
{"USER_ID":"UID00008","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin2","ROLE":"TESTER"},
{"USER_ID":"UID00009","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin3","ROLE":"REVIEWER"},
{"USER_ID":"UID00010","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin4","ROLE":"PMO"},
{"USER_ID":"UID00011","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin5","ROLE":"MANAGER"},
{"USER_ID":"UID00012","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin6","ROLE":"DEVELOPER"},
{"USER_ID":"UID00013","ENTERPRISE_ID":"admin7","ROLE":"DBA"}]
```

Comment: Could you also provide some example JSON for the content of your session storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, the `data` variable exists only within the scope of the `load` function:

```
function load() {

    var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loginInfo"));

    //...

}
```

And then you try to reference it outside of that function:

```
onclick='loadSegment(data[0])'
```

It doesn't exist at this point, so you can't reference it.  By contrast, in the second example you create the `data` variable in global scope, so it exists on the `window` object and can be referenced anywhere.

To encapsulate the `data` variable within that function, you'll need to supply the HTML you're creating with all of the information it needs to call the `loadSegment` function, not just an index reference.  Maybe serialize the whole value into the function call?  Maybe put values on `data-*` attributes?  Maybe move all the code into the function except the `data` variable and keep that on window scope?  You have options, depending on what you're trying to achieve overall.

---

Side note: You *might* not want to create something called `load` on the `window` object (or any other DOM object).  If not actual problems, that could cause confusion with other code.

Comment: How come the reference is not reachable to 'onclick'. I'm creating the table rows using  values from `data` variable. If table is created with all that data and passing that to a method the reference is gone?

Comment: @HarshitaSethi: You can use values from your object to construct the HTML and those values will be there, but you're trying to reference the variable itself from onclick, and that variable doesn't exist in that scope.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Changing the functionName will help 


function loadfun() 
{
 var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loginInfo"));
 var html = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].ENTERPRISE_ID + "</td>";
    html += "<td><button type='button' onclick='loadSegment(data[" + i +      "])'>...</button></td>";
    html += "<td>" + data[i].USER_ID + "</td></tr>";
 }
document.getElementById('roleTable').getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].innerHTML = html;
}


function loadSegment(o) {
alert('reading obj');
alert(JSON.stringify(o));
}
```

Comment: How will that help?